# Creating classes in python with a class variable

Tags: python

Information about making a class `Book` with (`self`, `title`, `author`, `edition`, `checkedOut`) `checkedOut` is a boolean.  Need a class variable called `libraryName` = YourName Library

Be sure to have a constructor (including default values for all variables), a `__str__` method, and an `__eq__` method.

The constructor should set the default values of title and author to unset, the edition to -1, and the checkedOut to False.

In your `__eq__` method, your comparison of the two strings (i.e. title and author) should allow for case differences.

In the `__str__` method when you output the value of the checkedOut instance variable, do not output `True` or `False`. Instead, your `__str__` method should output 'Yes' or 'No' for that particular variable.   Your method should also output the name of the library (i.e. the class variable) with three dashes on either side (or some other decoration) as shown below.

Your class should have a method called `checkOut()` that sets the `checkedOut` instance variable to `True`.

You should also have a method called `returnBook()` that sets the checkedOut instance variable to `False`.

I have created the class, made the class variable, I have started the `__eq__` and `__str__` methods.  I have attached where I started having trouble no need to post the class.

```
class Book
libraryName = '---PRPs Library---'
def __intit__(self, title, author, edition, checkedOut)
    self.title = title
    self.author = author
    self.edition = edition
    self.checkedOut = checkedOut
b1 = Book('Great Expectations', 'Charles Dickens', 3)
b2 = Book('Canterbury Tales', 'Geoffry Chaucer', 1, co=False)
b3 = Book('great expectations', 'charles dickens', 3)
def __str__ (self):
    while self.checkedOut:
        return ('Yes')
    else:
        return ('No')

def __eq__
    return (self.__class__ == other.__class__ and self.x == other.x)
def checkOut(self.checkedOut)
     checkOut = self.checkedOut True
def returnBook(self.checkedOut)
    checkOut = self.checkedOut False

b1 = Book('Great Expectations', 'Charles Dickens', 3)
b2 = Book('Canterbury Tales', 'Geoffry Chaucer', 1, co=False)
b2.checkout()
b3 = Book('great expectations', 'charles dickens', 3)
```

Comment: `while True:` is an infinite loop. But you unconditionally return `yes` from it, so it never iterates. What's the point of that? It will never execute the `else:` clause.

Comment: Why does `checkOut` need a loop? Are you mixing up `if` and `while` (this seems to be a common mistake of beginners)?

Comment: @Barmar I don't know if it does. I just know that while/if True I want it to output yes.  I am trying to to that, yes I believe I am making the beginners mistakes.  This is my first coding class ever

Comment: It seems like your `checkOut` method is doing what the `__str__` method is supposed to do, except it's not checking the value of the instance variable. The `checkOut` method is supposed to set the instance variable.

Comment: @Barmar could you look at it now if you don't mind I need help understanding the equality method, I don't really know what I'm doing there.

Comment: It seems like you need to go back and review basic syntax, like how to assign variables.

Comment: I agree this is a 5 week Course  summer course, I wish i would have taken it over a fall semester and not a summer.

Answer (score 0):

As the instructions say, the `checkOut` method is supposed to set the `checkedOut` attribute to `True`, and `returnBook` sets it to `False`. So they should be:

```
def checkOut(self):
    self.checkedOut = True

def returnBook(self):
    self.checkedOut = False
```

There's no need for `while` in these methods.

The `__str__` method is supposed to output all the information about the book.

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.checkedOut:
        co = 'Yes'
    else:
        co = 'No'
    return f'{self.title}, {self.edition} Edition by {self.author}; checked out: {co} --- {self.libraryName} ---'
```

The `__eq__` method has to compare the title and author:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.__class__ == other.__class__ and self.title.lower() == other.title.lower() and self.author.lower() = other.author.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a working version of your code. I hope it works as you expected.

**Code:**

```
class Book:
    library_name = "---PRPs Library---"

    def __init__(self, title, author, edition, checked_out=False):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.edition = edition
        self.checked_out = checked_out

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            "Title: {title}; Author: {author}; "
            "Edition: {edition}; Checked Out: {checked_out}".format(
                title=self.title,
                author=self.author,
                edition=self.edition,
                checked_out="Yes" if self.checked_out else "No",
            )
        )

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (
            self.__class__ == other.__class__
            and self.title.lower() == other.title.lower()
            and self.author.lower() == other.author.lower()
            and self.edition == other.edition
        )

    def check_out(self,):
        self.checked_out = True

    def return_book(self):
        self.checked_out = False


b1 = Book("Great Expectations", "Charles Dickens", 3)
print(b1)
b2 = Book("Canterbury Tales", "Geoffry Chaucer", 1, checked_out=False)
print(b2)
b2.check_out()
print(b2)
b3 = Book("great expectations", "charles dickens", 3)
print(b3)
print(b1 == b3)
b4 = Book("great expectations", "charles dickens", 5, checked_out=True)
print(b4)
b4.return_book()
print(b4)
print(b3 == b4)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Title: Great Expectations; Author: Charles Dickens; Edition: 3; Checked Out: No
Title: Canterbury Tales; Author: Geoffry Chaucer; Edition: 1; Checked Out: No
Title: Canterbury Tales; Author: Geoffry Chaucer; Edition: 1; Checked Out: Yes
Title: great expectations; Author: charles dickens; Edition: 3; Checked Out: No
True
Title: great expectations; Author: charles dickens; Edition: 5; Checked Out: Yes
Title: great expectations; Author: charles dickens; Edition: 5; Checked Out: No
False
```